# Protractor E2e test run in Sauce labs is not running all tests listed in the config

Tags: gruntjs, protractor, saucelabs

We use `grunt protractor runner` and have 49 specs to run.

When I run them in sauce labs, there are times it just runs x number of tests but not all. Any idea why? Are there any sauce settings to be passed over apart from user and key in my `protarctor conf.js`?

Using SauceLabs selenium server at http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub

```
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
.....

Ran 5 of 49 specs
5 specs, 0 failures
```

Comment: Do you see any `fdescribe` or `fit` left in the codebase when it does not run all of the tests?

Comment: No, I do not use those. None of the specs are commented or asked to not run. There are times they run them all and times they just run those 5. Its random

Comment: @alecxe you are right. somehow by typo one of the spec had a fdescribe and it was just that spec that was runing all the time. thx!

Comment: Okay, thanks, added as an answer with some more details. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of output is usually produced when there are "focused" tests present in the codebase. Check if there are `fdescribe`, `fit` in your tests.

As a side note, to avoid focused tests being committed to the repository, we've used static code analysis - [`eslint`](http://eslint.org/) with [`eslint-plugin-jasmine` plugin](https://github.com/tlvince/eslint-plugin-jasmine). Then, we've added a "pre-commit" git hook with the help of [`pre-git` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pre-git) that would run the `eslint` task before every commit eventually prohibiting any code style violations to be committed into the repository.